# Following regex is not working

Tags: sql, regex, t-sql

I have this constraint in the SQL Server statement.

```
([VehNo] like '[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z],[a-zA-Z][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][a-zA-Z]')
```

But when I try to insert data this is giving me error.

```
INSERT INTO [dbo].Car
VALUES ('SGD1234F','Ferrari','F30','2014-09-24','500000.00','500.00','excellent');
```

The error is as follows

> Msg 547, Level 16, State 0, Line 2 The INSERT statement conflicted
>   with the CHECK constraint "vehNo_ck_validity". The conflict occurred
>   in database "t322", table "dbo.Car", column 'VehNo'. The
>   statement has been terminated.

What is the change that I have to make?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your regexp contains an unwanted **comma**. I have added spaces to highlight comma in your regexp.

`[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z]  ,  [a-zA-Z][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][a-zA-Z]`

For such regexp, `VehNo` should be `SG,D1234F`

Remove extra comma and your insert statement will work.

This is another version of your regexp: `[a-zA-Z]{3}\d{4}[a-zA-Z]`

Comment: Minor point, I don't think your second version of the REGEX, while valid, will work in SQL Server

Comment: @Sparky Oh.. You may be right. I know about RegEx but dont know much about SQL Servers.